# Javascript If statement with html options

Tags: javascript

So ive been googling and searching but none of the answers seem to get me any closer.

The code below is to show how much of a discount you get depending on the price and membership. 
However to get an 8% discount you need Gold membership and to get 12% you need Platinum membership.

Right now it only considers the price tho.

```js
function discount() {
  
  var dollars = document.getElementById("cash").value;
  var member = document.getElementById("membership").text;
  
  if (dollars <= 99){
    
   document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
   
    
  }
  
    else if (dollars >= 100 <= 199){
    
   dollars = dollars - (dollars * 0.05);
   document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
  
  }
 
  else if (dollars >= 200 <= 299 && (member == Gold)){
    
   dollars = dollars - (dollars * 0.08)
    document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
  
  }
  
  else if (dollars >= 300  && member === Platinum){
    
   dollars = dollars - (dollars * 0.12)
    document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
  
  }
  
  
  
   
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cash" value="Skriv in kostnaden"> 
<br /><br />



<select id="membership">
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="None">None</option>
</select>

<br /><br />




<button onclick="discount()">Räkna ut din kostnad</button>

<p id="totalCash"></p>
```

Comment: what's this strange syntax `dollars >= 200 <= 299` ???

Comment: also what is Gold? you should write as `member === "Gold"`

Comment: `dollars >= 100 <= 199` evaluated like this: `(dollars >= 100) <= 199`. If `dollars=1`, then `dollars >= 100` is false, and `false <= 199` is true, so the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: then it is always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function discount() {
  
  var dollars = document.getElementById("cash").value;
  var member = document.getElementById("membership").value;
  
  console.log(dollars,member);
  
  if (dollars <= 99){
    
   document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
   
    
  }
  
    else if (dollars >= 100 && dollars <= 199){
    
   dollars = dollars - (dollars * 0.05);
   document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
  
  }
 
  else if (dollars >= 200 && dollars <= 299 && (member == 'Gold')){
    
   dollars = dollars - (dollars * 0.08)
    document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
  
  }
  
  else if (dollars >= 300  && member === 'Platinum'){
    
   dollars = dollars - (dollars * 0.12)
    document.getElementById("totalCash").innerHTML = "Din kostnad är " + dollars; 
  
  }
  
  
  
   
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cash" value="Skriv in kostnaden"> 
<br /><br />



<select id="membership">
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="None">None</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

you have a couple of errors in your js.  value not text and check your if statements.


<button onclick="discount()">Räkna ut din kostnad</button>

<p id="totalCash"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically what i did wrong was in the conditions statements ?

Comment: that and you were trying to get text instead of value on the select

Comment: Ohh right, last question. How come it works with singel quotation marks and not double ? Like 'Gold' instead of "Gold"